# How to query for get all products related a specific category in mysql database laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The following is my categories table:

[image]

This the product category table:

[image]

This is the products table:

[image]

I want to get the products by specific and single category for and display in the slider, like

- all products where category is electronic
- products where category is clothings
- all products where category is mobile

I am confused how to query and get the data by joining all the tables.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Use the relationships here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Please fix your question, images are not rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize eloquent and the relationship.
on your ProductCategory model do :

```
public function product(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'productId')
}
public function category(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'categoryID')
}
```

and then you can query like so:

```
ProductCategory::with(['product','category'])->where('categoryId', 191)->get();
```

Comment: thanks for your kind help i have achieve this by another trick...thanks alot man

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by defining relationships in your models as follows:

in your product model define a categories function

```
 public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'product_categories', 'productId', 'categoryId');
}
```

similary in your category model define a relationship for product

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_categories', 'categoryId', 'productId');
}
```

The product_categories table in this case is a pivot table, there are few rules to follow for pivot tables:

1. Pivot tables should be singular name of both tables, in your case it should be product_category table
2. Pivot table naming convention should be alphbetical, in your case it should be category_product
3. It is not necessary to create id and timestamps column in ppivot tables
4. You don't really need to create a model for pivot table

Also, not a rule but a suggestion your table columns should be snake case e.g category_id

After defining these functions in your models you can access the related data as follows:

```
$product = Product::find(27); //finding product by id
$product->categories;

$category = Category::find(187); //finding category by id 
$category->products;
```

Comment: thanks for your kind help i have achieve this by another trick...thanks alot man